# React arrow functions for all component methods

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Arrow functions are often used on methods that needs bindings to handle events.

Everywhere in the documentation and examples, lifecycle methods (`render`, `componentWillMount`, `constructor`, ...) are defined as regular functions, this ends up with mixed methods declaration style inside components.

Is it safe to use arrow functions for all component methods ?

I know it works fine for simple case, I'm looking for all potential downsides.

Comment: I can't give an informed answer, but you may find this article on the subject interesting (it explains why you shouldn't use arrow function for the construtor, for example): https://dmitripavlutin.com/when-not-to-use-arrow-functions-in-javascript/ This one is even more to the point: https://medium.com/@charpeni/arrow-functions-in-class-properties-might-not-be-as-great-as-we-think-3b3551c440b1

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is safe to use arrow functions if you want to for consistency.

```
componentDidMount(){
  console.log(this)
}
```

returns:

```
App {props: {…}, context: {…}, refs: {…}, updater: {…}, _reactInternalFiber: FiberNode, …}
context: {}
props: {}
refs: {}
state: null
updater:{isMounted: ƒ, enqueueSetState: ƒ, enqueueReplaceState: ƒ, enqueueForceUpdate: ƒ}
_reactInternalFiber:FiberNode {tag: 2, key: null, type: ƒ, stateNode: App, return: FiberNode, …}
_reactInternalInstance:{_processChildContext: ƒ}
isMounted:(...)
replaceState:(...)
__proto__:Component
```

And

```
componentDidMount = () => {
  console.log(this)
}
```

returns:

```
App {props: {…}, context: {…}, refs: {…}, updater: {…}, componentDidMount: ƒ, …}
componentDidMount:ƒ ()
context:{}
props:{}
refs:{}
state:null
updater:{isMounted: ƒ, enqueueSetState: ƒ, enqueueReplaceState: ƒ, enqueueForceUpdate: ƒ}
_reactInternalFiber:FiberNode {tag: 2, key: null, type: ƒ, stateNode: App, return: FiberNode, …}
_reactInternalInstance:{_processChildContext: ƒ}
isMounted:(...)
replaceState:(...)
__proto__:Component
```

Both these methods log the exact same class except the class with the `componentDidMount = () => {}` has componentDidMount as an attribute as opposed to a method but is still called in the same way.